# Upload file to S3 bucket: a null reference exception on await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, _bucket)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to upload a file to S3 bucket, but have a null reference exception on
`await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, _bucket)`

```
public class FileUploadService : IFileUploadService
{
    private readonly string _bucket;

    public FileUploadService()
    {
        _bucket = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["S3Bucket"];
    }

    public async Task UploadFile(string filePath, CognitoAWSCredentials cred)
    {
        IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(cred);
        TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
        await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, _bucket);
    }
}
```

Here is a relevant part of the stacktrace of the exception:

> at
> Amazon.S3.Util.BucketRegionDetector.GetUsEast1ClientFromCredentials(ImmutableCredentials
> credentials)    at
> Amazon.S3.Util.BucketRegionDetector.GetHeadBucketPreSignedUrl(String
> bucketName, ImmutableCredentials credentials)    at
> Amazon.S3.Util.BucketRegionDetector.d__13.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Amazon.S3.Util.BucketRegionDetector.d__12.MoveNext()
> ...

Not sure what I am doing wrong as I am new to AWS. I retrieve `CognitoAWSCredentials` in a following way:

```
string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CLIENT_ID"];
string poolId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USERPOOL_ID"];
RegionEndpoint region = RegionEndpoint.EnumerableAllRegions.First(q => q.SystemName == "us-east-1");
provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), region);    

CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolId, clientId, provider);
CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(username, clientId, userPool, provider);

AuthFlowResponse context = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
{
    Password = password
});

CognitoAWSCredentials cred = user.GetCognitoAWSCredentials(poolId, region);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your credentials are invalid for the UploadAsync call.

(See: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1166 for information as to why you get the null reference exception.)

You should be calling GetCognitoAWSCredentials(poolId, region) with an Identity Pool Id, not a User Pool Id.  See the "Use AWS Resources after Authentication" section here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cognito-authentication-extension.html

To avoid the null reference exception, call GetCredentialsAsync on your CognitoAWSCredentials before making any S3 calls using them.  Something like:

```
public async Task UploadFile(string filePath, CognitoAWSCredentials cred)
{
    try
    {
        // AmazonS3Client behaves badly if its GetCredentialsAsync() call throws certain exceptions,
        // so try for ourselves first.  We are doomed anyway if we can't get proper credentials.
        _ = await cred.GetCredentialsAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Exception getting credentials: {e.Message}");
        throw;
    }

    IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(cred);
    TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
    await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, _bucket);
}
```

This way, you can handle the exception from GetCredentialsAsync() yourself.